# Upload tab delimited txt file using form, then make into PHP arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, file, tabs, delimited

I'm trying parse a tab delemited text file into a set of PHP arrays, and help would be very much appreciated.

The .txt wil look like this (tab delimited not spaces)

```
data1a data1b data1c data1d
data2a data2b data2c data2d
data3a data3b data3c data3d
data4a data4b data4c data4d
```

and so on

I wish the PHP arrays to look like this

```
$arrayA = array('data1a', 'data2a', 'data3a', 'data4a');
$arrayB = array('data1b', 'data2b', 'data3b', 'data4b');
$arrayC = array('data1c', 'data2c', 'data3c', 'data4c');
$arrayD = array('data1d', 'data2d', 'data3d', 'data4d');
```

And I need the .txt file uploaded by a simple html form, e.g.

```
<form action="form.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <label for="file">Filename:</label>
  <input type="file" name="file" id="file" /> 
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Any ideas on the code to place inside form.php?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider the content of your `text.txt` file

```
FristLineFirstData  FirstLineSecondData FirstLineThirdData
SecondLineFirstData SecondLineSecondData    SecondLineThirdData
```

Tab separed.

And the script :

```
<?php
$file = "text.txt";// Your Temp Uploaded file
$handle = fopen($file, "r"); // Make all conditions to avoid errors
$read = file_get_contents($file); //read
$lines = explode("\n", $read);//get
$i= 0;//initialize
foreach($lines as $key => $value){
    $cols[$i] = explode("\t", $value);
    $i++;
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($cols); //explore results
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

will return

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => FristLineFirstData
            [1] => FirstLineSecondData
            [2] => FirstLineThirdData
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => SecondLineFirstData
            [1] => SecondLineSecondData
            [2] => SecondLineThirdData
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is a barebone solution for your problem:

```
<?php
 $error = false;

 if (isset($_POST) && isset($_POST['submit']) && isset($_FILES) {)
    $file = $_FILES['file'];
    if (file_exists($_FILES['tmp_name'])){
       $handle = fopen($_FILES['tmp_name']);
       $data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, '\t');
    }
    // do your data processing here
    // ...
    // do your processing result display there
    // ...
    // or redirect to another page.
 }
 if ($error) {
   // put some error message here if necessary
 }
 // form display below
 ?>
 <!-- HTML FORM goes here --!>
 <?
 }
 ?>
```

The file data will be all grouped in the same array `$data`, indexed by the corresponding line number in the file.

See:

- [`fgetcsv`](http://php.net/fgetcsv)
- [`$_FILES`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php)

on the PHP documentation website.